# python: plot with a repeated legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have 3 files to plot (pos_Felix, pos_Iando, pos_Fabiotto). For some reason I have to put them together in a unique file. A reproducible code follows:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
import numpy

pos_Felix = numpy.array([ [  3.05150657e-01,  -7.33839341e-01],
                        [  3.24785115e-01,  -5.70699171e-01],
                        [ -1.90952119e-02,  -9.31596157e-01],
                        [  1.01292710e+00,  -3.75807265e-01],
                        [  3.32793456e-01,  -6.54133767e-01]])

pos_Iando = numpy.array([ [  3.41211808e-04,  -1.43754261e-02],
                        [ -1.18384581e-01,  -4.84193704e-01]])

pos_Fabiotto = numpy.array([ [ -4.63776141e-01,   1.62560557e+00]])

pos_all = numpy.concatenate([pos_Felix,pos_Iando,pos_Fabiotto],axis=0)


myColors = ['green']*pos_Felix.shape[0] + ['red']*(pos_Iando.shape[0]+pos_Fabiotto.shape[0])

myShapes    =   ['.']*pos_Felix.shape[0]     + ['^']*pos_Iando.shape[0]       + ['*']*pos_Fabiotto.shape[0]
myLabels    =   ['Felix']*pos_Felix.shape[0] + ['Iando']*pos_Iando.shape[0]   + ['Fabiotto']*pos_Fabiotto.shape[0]



pylab.figure()
pylab.title("Multi Dimensional Scaling")
pylab.xlabel("X")
pylab.ylabel("Y")
for i in range(pos_all.shape[0]):
    pylab.plot(pos_all[i,0],pos_all[i,1],myShapes[i], color=myColors[i], label=myLabels[i])
pylab.legend(loc="upper left")

pylab.show()
```

In a few words, I have to plot a sequence of points (I am sure that the "for" construct is not the best one, but at least it works so far), each one with a colour, each one belonging to a category ("Felix", "Iando" and "Fabiotto"), each one with its marker. The graph is ok, except the legend. It is of length 8 instead of 3. I get the following image (in red what I would like to remove):

[image]

I am sure there is a quick way to solve my issue... but i do not know which one!
ps= I know I could create a list of legends with only 3 elements in the right places and "None" for the others, but in my real case I have very long lists and i need an automated procedure.

Comment: Since you hardcode the colors and names, you could as well hardcode the legends entries. This example does not scale to "the real case" with "very long" lists. Possible answers need to know how you do the mapping between data and label, color, and shapes in the "real case".

Comment: I've tried to make it more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if all repeated labels are consecutive:

```
pylab.figure()
pylab.title("Multi Dimensional Scaling")
pylab.xlabel("X")
pylab.ylabel("Y")
last_label = None
for i in range(pos_all.shape[0]):
    label = myLabels[i]
    if label == last_label:
        label = None
    else:
        last_label = label
    pylab.plot(pos_all[i,0],pos_all[i,1],myShapes[i], color=myColors[i], label=label)
pylab.legend(loc="upper left")

pylab.show()
```

You could also make a dictionary with `{label:style}` and keep a list of already labelled plots, to make sure every data set with the same name gets the same style and is only labelled if it hasn't already (`if label in list_labels` instead of `label == last_label`).

Comment: Yes,at the end I had solved with something similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you seem to have access to the individual arrays for each name, you can simply produce 3 plots, one for each name.

```
pylab.figure()
pylab.title("Multi Dimensional Scaling")
pylab.xlabel("X")
pylab.ylabel("Y")

pylab.plot(pos_Felix[:,0],pos_Felix[:,1],".", color="green", label="Felix")
pylab.plot(pos_Iando[:,0],pos_Iando[:,1],"^", color="red", label="Iando")
pylab.plot(pos_Fabiotto[:,0],pos_Fabiotto[:,1],"*", color="red", label="Fabiotto")

pylab.legend(loc="upper left")

pylab.show()
```